# Discretize values/binning for missing data

Tags: r, repeated-measures, binning

I’m running an experiment where pairs make ratings after answering questions. There are 15 minute intervals where they attempt to answer 12 questions, but each pair makes it through a different number of questions. I would like to average their ratings throughout all the time points, but then I would only have a few pairs’ data making up the last few data points. Is there a way to weight each pair’s ratings equally by sorting their responses into bins/discretizing the values? So if pair 1 made 10 ratings and pair 2 made 5, and I had 5 bins, I could put 2 ratings/bin for pair 1 and 1 rating/bin for pair 2. Except in reality, I’d have imperfect numbers...Any tips for discretizing values/bins in R when I want to average this kind of incomplete data over time where different pairs answered different amounts of questions?